# Checking if the table has rows results in Null Pointer Exception in SQLiite Android

Tags: android, sqlite, count

I want to check if the table has rows and if it contains, then I want to delete it. Below is my code for checking if table has rows in it.

```
     boolean empty = true;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM TABLE_NAME",null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (cursor.getInt(0) > 0)
    {
        empty = false;
    }
    else
    {
        empty= true;
    }
    return  empty;
```

I even tried checking with below code,

```
    boolean empty = true;
    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_NAME", null);
    if (cur != null && cur.moveToFirst()) {
        empty = (cur.getInt (0) == 0);
    }
    cur.close();

    return empty;
```

Both of the above code, throws NullPointerException in line

("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_NAME", null);

Any help would be great !! Thanks

Comment: post the exception also...It may seems that your `db` object is `null`.

Comment: better to do `int count = cur.getCount();` is return the effected rows.

Comment: If it's throwing on that line, then `db` is probably null.

Comment: @MD `Cursor#getCount()` is kinda pointless on a `COUNT` query.

Comment: Then what would be the correct way ? @MikeM.

Comment: and no database is not null @MikeM.

Comment: @MD "select count(*)" will always have one row (even if the table is empty), so in this case `getCount() == 1`

Comment: Could you please edit and post as answer @pskink

Comment: But why its throwing null pointer exception in raw query line ? @pskink

Comment: simply `db` is null here

Comment: But I have a database with data in it. @pskink

Comment: but you did not initialize your `db` variable

Comment: Yea i didn't initialize db its not throwing exception now but its not deleting the data from the table. I want to delete records if there is data in database. I think the above code returns false @pskink

Comment: you think? better just debug your code to be sure

Comment: Its returning false . I debugged it @pskink

Comment: it returns false if `cursor.getInt(0) > 0` is it really what you want?

Comment: I just found out . Thanks !! It works now @pskink

Answer (score 1):

Android comes with a utility class called DatabaseUtils which has a method queryNumEntries that can take your database object and table name as parameter and return the total number of records on that database. Quite a clean way. You don’t need to be writing ‘Select Count(*) from mytable‘ kind of stuffs.

```java
public long count() {
    return DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db,'myTablename');
}
```

next to delete he rows if your database is not empty try
deleteAll to delete all the rows in dB, or use delete_byID() by passing the ID as parameter to the row which you want to delete.

```java
public int deleteAll(){
    return sqLiteDatabase.delete(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, null);
}

public void delete_byID(int id){
    sqLiteDatabase.delete(MYDATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ID+"="+id, null);
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.